# Android: Error when saving file to SD Card

Tags: java, android, image, permissions, sd-card

I've been trying to save a JPG image to the SD Card in order to then scale it down and display it in an ImageView (due to the original size causing an Out of memory error).

Here's the method I use to save the file:

```
public void saveImage(String src) throws IOException{
        URL url = new URL (src); 
        InputStream input = url.openStream(); 
        try {     
            File storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (new File(storagePath, "myImage.jpg"));     
            try {         
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];         
                int bytesRead = 0;         
                while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
                        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);         
                }     
            }  
            finally {         
                output.close();     
            } 
        } 

        finally {     
            input.close(); 
        }
    }
```

Then here is when I call on that method and then try to load a scaled down image into memory and put it into the ImageView:

```
try {
            saveImage(src);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        options.inSampleSize = 20;



        File storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(storagePath, "myImage.jpg");

        Bitmap scaledDownImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);


        imageFrame1.setImageBitmap(scaledDownImage);
```

However, when I try to run this, I get the LogCat message saying:

> "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/myImage.jpg: open failed :
>   EACCES (Permission denied)"

I've also made sure to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to the manifest.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit: The error occurs at line 107 and 72, meaning that it occurs when I try to save the image.

Bump: Anyone? Would really appreciate some suggestions.

Comment: are you sure you have saved the image before you try and open it? Plus, `inSampleSize = 20` seems a little high.

Comment: The error happens when I try to save it, so no probably not. And the image is absolutely massive, and I want to scale it down to be pretty small, so the 20 was just a starting point.

Comment: Can you share stack trace of `url.openStream()`? You are not trying to do network operation in main thread, are you?

Comment: I am, but that's not the problem, the networking stuff goes fine, it's when I try to save to the SD card that the logcat error comes out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! Turns out all I needed to change was the size of the byte buffer in the saveImage method. It was at 1024 but after upping it to 8192 it's working fine!

Thanks for everyone elses suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

use the following:

```
String  path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                .toString() + File.separator + "myImage.jpg";
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (path,true);
```

Comment: I edited the code to put that in and I still get the same error message, at the same place.